# Loc function on conditions in pandas returns Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I genuinely don't get why it returns NaN

I have a df and i need to create one more column based on other columns values, this method always worked.

```
train.loc[(train.region == 'Latin America') & (train.sales_channel == 'Online'), 'expense'] = 47
train.loc[(train.region == 'Latin America') & (train.sales_channel == 'Partnerships'), 'expense'] = 63
train.loc[(train.region == 'Latin America') & (train.sales_channel == 'Direct Sales'), 'expense'] = 89
train.loc[(train.region == 'Europe') & (train.sales_channel == 'Online'), 'expense'] = 69
```

and i get back this

[image]

Comment: `train.sales_channel` change to `train['sales_channel']`

Comment: @Wen i tried that already and just tried again, the same nans

Comment: can you print your column name , whether there is blank ?

Comment: @Wen thanks yes, I checked the column values for nan, all solved, I took columns values from specification file and in actual file, there was a bit of different spelling

Comment: Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
train.loc[(train['region'] == 'Latin America') & (train['sales_channel'] == 'Partnerships'),['expense']] = 63
```